# Node.js, Protocol buffers and ubuntu - How to get it to work?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

Here are the steps I used to try and load a proto file in node.js.  Overall, how do I get protocol buffers to work with node.js?

1) Dowloaded and installed protocol buffers into this location.

```
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/protobuf-2.4.1
```

2) Downloaded this protobuf-for-node fix from this repo.  I places the folder in the node_modules folder of my node.js app folder.

```
git://github.com/pzgz/protobuf-for-node.git
```

3) Ran the following command

```
cd node_modules/protobuf-for-node
PROTOBUF=~/Downloads/protobuf-2.4.1 /usr/local/bin/node-waf configure clean build
```

4) Moved the following files to these locations:

```
cp node_modules/protobuf-for-node/protobuf_for_node.h /usr/local/include/node
cp node_modules/protobuf-for-node/build/Release/protobuf_for_node_lib.so /usr/local/lib
```

5) Ran the following to build the feeds.proto example that ships with node.js

```
cd node_modules/protobuf-for-node/example
protoc --descriptor_set_out=feeds.desc --include_imports feeds.proto
```

6) In the app, I added this line.

```
var express = require('express'), routes = require('./routes');
var fs = require('fs');
var puts = require('util').puts;
url = require('url');
moment = require('moment');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var Schema = require('protobuf_for_node').Schema;
var schema = new Schema(fs.readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/protobuf-for-node/example/feeds.desc'));
```

7) Here is my error.

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'protobuf_for_node'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/app.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
```

Comment: It's name is probably protobuf

Comment: Tried..nope...this line is from google example. var Schema = require('protobuf_for_node').Schema;

Answer (score 2):

Consider using this fork of the library instead:

https://github.com/chrisdew/protobuf/

It seems to be more actively maintained and has better documentation.  Installing it was npm was trivial and doing a `require('protobuf')` is working fine for me.

For Ubuntu I needed to install the following to get the package installed with npm and get the proto file compiled:

`sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler`

It looks like you already have those but installed them by hand.

Comment: could any explain who protobuf works here. what is .desc file? can we create buffer without schema? plz share some complete example code..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I did for https://github.com/chrisdew/protobuf/issues/29 - most users won't need the complication of bytes fields.

buftest.proto

```
package com.chrisdew.buftest;

message BufTest {
  optional float num  = 1;
  optional bytes payload = 2;
}
```

buftest.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Schema = require('protobuf').Schema;

// "schema" contains all message types defined in buftest.proto|desc.
var schema = new Schema(fs.readFileSync('buftest.desc'));

// The "BufTest" message.
var BufTest = schema['com.chrisdew.buftest.BufTest'];

var ob = { num: 42 };
ob.payload = new Buffer("Hello World");

var proto = BufTest.serialize(ob);
console.log('proto.length:', proto.length);

var outOb = BufTest.parse(proto);
console.log('unserialised:', JSON.stringify(outOb));

var payload = new Buffer(outOb.payload);
console.log(payload);
```

Makefile: (second line begins with a TAB not spaces)

```
all:
    protoc --descriptor_set_out=buftest.desc --include_imports buftest.proto
```

output:

```
$ node buftest.js 
proto.length: 18
unserialised: {"num":42,"payload":{"0":72,"1":101,"2":108,"3":108,"4":111,"5":32,"6":87,"7":111,"8":114,"9":108,"10":100,"length":11}}

payload: <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64>
```